# How to map pandas Groupby dataframe with sum values to another dataframe using non-unique column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe **df1** and **df2**. Where i need to find `df1['seq']` by doing a groupby on `df2` and taking the sum of the column `df2['sum_column']`. Below are sample data and my current solution.

**df1**

```
id    code amount  seq
234     3    9.8    ?
213     3    18
241     3    6.4
543     3    2
524     2    1.8
142     2    14
987     2    11
658     3    17
```

**df2**

```
c_id  name role    sum_column
1     Aus  leader    6
1     Aus  client    1
1     Aus  chair     7
2     Ned  chair     8
2     Ned  leader    3
3     Mar  client    5
3     Mar  chair     2
3     Mar  leader    4

grouped = df2.groupby('c_id')['sum_column'].sum()
df3 = grouped.reset_index()
```

**df3**

```
c_id  sum_column
 1      14
 2      11
 3      11
```

The next step where am having issues is to map the **df3** to **df1** and conduct a conditional check to see if `df1['amount']` is greater then `df3['sum_column']`.

```
df1['seq'] = np.where(df1['amount'] > df1['code'].map(df3.set_index('c_id')[sum_column]), 1, 0)
```

printing out `df1['code'].map(df3.set_index('c_id')['sum_column'])`, I get only `NaN` values.

Does anyone know what am doing wrong here?

Expected results:
**df1**

```
id    code amount  seq
234     3    9.8    0
213     3    18     1
241     3    6.4    0
543     3    2      0
524     2    1.8    0
142     2    14     1
987     2    11     0
658     3    17     1
```

Comment: Why do you even need df3 for the final result you posted? It seems you're just comparing `code` and `amount` in the original df1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution should be simplify with remove `.reset_index()` for `df3` and pass `Series` to `map`:

```
s = df2.groupby('c_id')['sum_column'].sum()
df1['seq'] = np.where(df1['amount'] > df1['code'].map(s), 1, 0)
```

Alternative with casting boolean mask to integer for `True, False` to `1,0`:

```
df1['seq'] = (df1['amount'] > df1['code'].map(s)).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df1)
    id  code  amount  seq
0  234     3     9.8    0
1  213     3    18.0    1
2  241     3     6.4    0
3  543     3     2.0    0
4  524     2     1.8    0
5  142     2    14.0    1
6  987     2    11.0    0
7  658     3    17.0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget add quote for `sum_column`

```
df1['seq']=np.where(df1['amount'] > df1['code'].map(df3.set_index('c_id')['sum_column']), 1, 0)
```